Type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<Select<Option, false, GroupBase<Option>>> | undefined'. in react-select
I am getting this TypeScript error when I use forwardRef in my Select component while using react-select.
Type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to type
'LegacyRef<Select<Option, false, GroupBase<Option>>> | undefined'.

import Select from "react-select";

export const SelectInput = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, SelectInputProps>(
 (props, ref) =>{
    ...

    return(
     <div>
       <Select
         key="random-key"
         ref={ref}
         ....
        />
     </div>
    )
 }
)

I used the same type and forwardRef with an input element and everything seems to be fine but I having issues here. I have tried several solution such as this one useRef TypeScript - not assignable to type LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> it didn't work for me.
This is a full log of the error
Type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<Select<Option, false, GroupBase<Option>>> | undefined'.

Type '(instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<Select<Option, false, GroupBase<Option>>> | undefined'.
    Type '(instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(instance: Select<Option, false, GroupBase<Option>> | null) => void | (() => VoidOrUndefinedOnly)'.
      Types of parameters 'instance' and 'instance' are incompatible.
        Type 'Select<Option, false, GroupBase<Option>> | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement | null'.
          Type 'Select<Option, false, GroupBase<Option>>' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLInputElement': accept, align, alt, autocomplete, and 352 more.


The issue arises because the ref you are forwarding is of type HTMLInputElement, but the ref for the react-select component expects a type that aligns with its internal Select component, not a DOM HTMLInputElement.
You need to adjust the ref type to match what react-select expects. react-select uses a custom Select component and not a native HTML input, so you must forward the ref with the correct type.
Do this:
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import Select, { GroupBase, Props as SelectProps } from "react-select";

interface Option {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}

interface SelectInputProps extends SelectProps<Option, false, GroupBase<Option>> {
  // You can extend or add custom props here if needed
}

export const SelectInput = forwardRef<Select<Option, false, GroupBase<Option>>, SelectInputProps>(
  (props, ref) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          {...props}
          ref={ref}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
);


Wanna find out an easier way? Get rid of forwardRef component just like that
export const SelectInput = <Option, IsMulti extends boolean = false, Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>>({
    id,
    name,
    className,
    //...other select input properties
    ...props,
}: SelectInputProps<Option, IsMulti, Group> & { myRef: React.Ref<HTMLDivElement> }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Select
                key="random-key"
                ref={props.myRef}
                //...
            />
        </div>
    )
}

Usage:
interface OptionType { // convert into your own type
    id: number
    name: string
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
    const selectRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (selectRef.current) console.log("select component: ", selectRef.current)
    }, [])

    return (
        <Select<OptionType>
            myRef={selectRef}
            options={options}
            //...
        />
        
    )
}

